# Changing prefix build for static asset in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I just wonder if we can configure name of prefix asset in nextjs 13

when we running build of next application it will produce new folder into project with name "out" folder and there will be several folder inside there.

When we using `<Image>` from next/image it will build into `/_next/static/media/myimage.svg`

Is it possible to us, maybe in config.next.json to change all image path to something else like `/_next/static/asset/myimage.svg` or `/_next/images/myimage.svg`

I just wonder if we can change build prefix in nextjs

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: something from security blocking access to /media, so I think if we can find alternatif from code level by changing next build directory name